# ios 8 how to make entire app stretch to bigger screen instead of autolayout

Tags: uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios8, autolayout

I have been testing my app with and without autolayout. Without autolayout, it looks great on the iphone 5, but on iphone 6 and 6+, everything gets stuck on the top left. 
With autolayout everything looks well spaced out but i don't like how i have a lot of empty space all over everywhere. It sort of looks like I don't have enough content on the screen.

So I went to mockuphone.com and uploaded a iphone 5 screenshot for a iphone 6 model to see how it will look and surprisingly it looks great stretched out. So my question is, how do I make my entire app simply stretch out instead of using autolayout?

My app doesn't use images or anything of that sort, so I think i don't really need to use autolayout if simple stretch does the job. I have table views which just need to be stretched (zoomed in sort of) and they would look good. For example if you have a square, regardless of if it's stretched or not, it will still look like a square without looking ugly. Is there a way to simple make all my view controllers simply stretch to fit screen?

Comment: You should just adjust your autolayout constraints to give the appearance you want.

Comment: You can exactly achieve that using autolayout. You just need to learn how to use it ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you remove any launch screen file, or launch images for the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus, the devices will revert to upscaling the app to fit their larger screens.

As shim suggested, auto layout is the preferred way to go.  I'd recommend taking advantage of size classes (and universal storyboards).  Everything will look sharper running at native resolution, and users will appreciate that you support the larger screens on their new devices.

Comment: i don't believe that's correct. I have only one launch storyboard file with autolayout disabled. Yet on iphone 6, instead of upscaling, it puts everything to the left corner